# How do I read this kind of tables?

Tags: probability

I have found myself again having to take university-access exams but the contents of the exam on the Maths side changed a bit since I took it last time, so I am here to ask you a kinda easy question, for I have not found any content about it everywhere I could reach.

My question is simple: how do I read this kind of table:

[ExerciseA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeZbB.png)

In case you need, I'll provide a translation of the exercise itself:

a)An industrial plant has three machines. Machine A produces $500$ daily capacitors, which $3$% of them are defective, Machine B produces $700$ with $4$% defective and Machine C  produces $800$ with $2$% defective. At the end of day we choose one randomly.

a1) Calculate the probability of it beign defective

a2) if it's defective, calculate the probability of it coming from Machine A

b) We throw a perfect dice five times. Beign X "multiples of 3 you can get as a result"

b1) Calculate the average of X and it's standar deviation.

b2) Calculate the probability of getting four or more multiples of $3$.

First, I'm not asking you to solve the exercise (for my intention is to beign able to solve it by myself and I'd like to have the least help possible), just learning to read the table. I am providing the translation as a mean of helping anyone who reads this question. Second, excuse if the translation isn't word by word, but I felt I had to prime the meaning of the sentence over all.

Also, thenk you very much beforehand, and excuse me if this was too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the binomial distribution table, with $n = 5$, $k$ = number of trials, and $p$ being the probability of success.  The Formula for this is $$B(n,p) = \left( \begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array} \right) p^kq^{n-k}$$ where $q = 1-p$ (the probability of failure).

For example, let's take $k = 3, p=0.40$.  We should then have

$$B(5,3) = \left( \begin{array}{c} 5 \\ 3 \end{array} \right) (0.40)^3(0.60)^2 = 0.2304.$$  If we compare this value with table entry for $k = 3, p=0.40$, they match.